# Can Firebase Phone Number Auth be implemented on a Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I intend to implement all my application logic online but I want to know if it's possible to make a phone number authentication on cloud functions with the auto verification callback.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in providers of Firebase Authentication needs to be called from within the client-side SDKs. Signing in with these providers is not meant to be initiated from server-side code, even though the accounts can be read and [manipulated from server-side code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

You can definitely [implement your own phone authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), and then use the Admin SDK to mint Firebase tokens for that.